# Identify if the reversed code is Obfuscated or n I not

Tags: .net-4.0, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have an access to an old managemnt system for my client and he wants to add more to it. I was able to contact the guy who originally wrote the main DLLs and then I got control and started building around them. But now, I need to extend the original too and I have no option but to reverse engineer.

I tried Reflector Pro and JustDecompile but the obtained source was full of errors. ILSpy works well but still, here is a sample code that I get from ILSpy:

```
    private static object ParseIntoValue(string stringValue, string targetType)
    {
        if (targetType != null)
        {
            if (<PrivateImplementationDetails>{C6507306-5ECF-4D05-8EE4-BD4D7781AC4E}.$$method0x600080f-1 == null)
            {
                <PrivateImplementationDetails>{C6507306-5ECF-4D05-8EE4-BD4D7781AC4E}.$$method0x600080f-1 = new Dictionary<string, int>(12)
                {
                    ...
                };
            }
            int num;
            if (<PrivateImplementationDetails>{C6507306-5ECF-4D05-8EE4-BD4D7781AC4E}.$$method0x600080f-1.TryGetValue(targetType, out num))
            {
                object result;
                switch (num)
                {

                cases are here...

                default:
                    goto IL_2A6;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        IL_2A6:
        return null;
    }
```

Its pretty clear there is some form of obfuscation applied here. Reversed code from JustDecompile and Reflector Pro was completely useless. With ILSpy, I'm able to compile a few of the projects without any modifications at all.

I need help to identify this obfuscation (if that's the case). The original developer says he didn't obfuscate. I'm not so sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Since it's .NET 4.0 it could be lambda expressions. Those are difficult to decompile I've been told. Why not get the sources from the original developer?

Comment: The original guy is now on vacations and I doubt he'll be handing over the sources. Before he comes back and says the dog ate his Hard drives, I'm preparing on my own to re-write everything on .Net 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *PrivateImplementationDetails* in the decompiled code could be an auto-implemented property.

If you replace `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{C6507306-5ECF-4D05-8EE4-BD4D7781AC4E}.$$method0x600080f-1` with a property the code seems to make sense.

```
Dictionary<string, int> MyProp { get; set;}

private static object ParseIntoValue(string stringValue, string targetType)
{
    if (targetType != null)
    {
        if (MyProp == null)
        {
           MyProp = new Dictionary<string, int>(12)
            {
                ...
            };
        }
        int num;
        if (MyProp.TryGetValue(targetType, out num))
        {
          ....
```

Comment: Verified this is the output of an auto-implemented property cast as Dictionary when reflected in ILSpy. I wonder why it has so much trouble with Dictionary<,> ... { get; set; } ?